# Aptana sometimes hangs on Mac OSX after workspace change

Tags: aptana, osx-mavericks, workspace, freeze

I love Aptana and use it heavily, however I started to have weird and annoying problems - every now and then Aptana process hangs in the background and I can't start it or kill the process - only solution I found is to restart my Mac. I use MacBook Pro with Mavericks on it, and I have latest Aptana release. I also use SVN plugin created for Eclipse studio.
The first symptom I have is another Aptana icon appearing on my Dock bar, one is permanently present there and suddenly another one appears - I think it happens on Workspace change. I can no longer switch to Aptana using original icon, I have to use the one that appeared afterwards. After I quit Aptana instance represented by the new icon, I can't activate it any more and I have an Aptana process that I can't kill, and it won't show if I type ps -A in terminal.

If anybody has any clue on how this happens, I'd like to avoid it - just don't tell me not to switch my workspaces since I depend on it - I'm a professional web developer working for several companies and workspaces are a way to organise my work

If anyone knows how to kill this aptana instance, that would be a temporary solution too - killing it from Activity monitor or Force Quitting does not help, I just get a warning that I'll "lose any unsaved changes" but after I click on Force Quit nothing happens - the process is still there.

And yes, this does not happen with any other app on my mac - thanks for asking :D

Thanks,
Viktor

Comment: I have exactly the same issues, which started after I updated Aptana to 3.6.0.201407100658. With me it works to use Force Quit though.

Comment: I need to Force Quit every time I open Aptana. Using build: 3.6.0.201407100658. This happened ever since I updated to the latest version.

Comment: Exactly my experience… does anyone have an idea how to solve this already?

Comment: Have you guys tried to quit Chrome or some other browser? It might prove the relation... Also, has anyone experienced a loss of Connection icon in Project tree view? It happens to me for the second time... Very annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might be experiencing this issue - here's what came out in the end
I accidentally found out that if I close Chrome, hanging Aptana instance also exits and I can normally start it again. So try to shut down Chrome and the problem might be solved.
This applies to Aptana Studio 3.4.2.201308081805 - I have yet to install the latest version but it might be the same thing.

I'm wondering has this anything to do with Java? Only thing I see in common

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to kill it:

```
$ ps -ef | grep Aptana
```

then, kill the process

```
$ kill -9 <PID>
```

substitute  with the actual process ID

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, and according to https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8275 it will be fixed in release 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana's bug tracker marks this as fixed for release 3.6.1: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8264
 However, it was marked fixed in August, and the most recent release available for download is still 3.6.0.
(Anyone with Aptana have an idea when the fix will be released?)

Comment: I have installed 3.6.1 a while ago and it does behave better but I can't say the problem has gone completely. However, I noticed few more things get unblocked if I quit Chrome - I still think there may be a relation between the two

Comment: Hi Vic, where did you get that 3.6.1 version? Did you build yourself?